# How to remove "p.485" inside the brackets with R?

Tags: r, regex

I have:`

```
String="(anthony,2019, p.485)"
```

Desidered Output:

```
String="(anthony,2019)"
```

i want removed only p.485.

I use the regex: `

```
gsub("\\( \\,p\\.[0-9]\\)","",String)
```

but it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `sub("\\s*,\\s*p\\.[0-9]+", "", String)`

Comment: The problem is that your regex does not match the thing you want to replace. You should use a regex debugger like regex101.com to figure out how to get it to do what you want. You appear to be missing a qualifier on the number (so you match only a single number, not 3), you include the parentheses in the regex (so they’d also be removed) and you don’t account for the name and year inside the parentheses (it will only match if the pattern is `( ,p.4)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match `,` followed by a space, 'p' and one or more digits (`\\d+`), replace by blank (`""`) in the replacement

```
sub(", p\\.\\d+", "", String)
#[1] "(anthony,2019)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also try this slightly inefficient regex:

```
String="(anthony,2019, p.485)"
gsub(",\\s\\w.\\d{1,}","",String,perl=TRUE)
#[1] "(anthony,2019)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it might be a bit fragile, since it depends on there not being any spaces after commas except for the last one:

```
gsub("[,] [^,)]+","", String)
[1] "(anthony,2019)"
```

That fragility afflicts akrun's answer as well. A more robust solution would be to match on the last comma but leave in the closing paren. This solution will locate that last comma and excise everything up to but not included the closing paren:

```
gsub("(.+)([,] [^,]+)([)])","\\1\\3", String)  # 3 capture classes

[1] "(anthony,2019)"                           # return only first and third
```